# Algoritmo de Saque Bancário em C usando recursividade

Tags: c, recursão

Estou com dúvidas sobre um algoritmo de saque de banco em C. Antes de mais nada é melhor passar o enunciado:

> Caixas automáticos nos bancos são uma invenção ótima, mas, às vezes, a gente precisa de dinheiro trocado e a máquina entrega notas de R$100,00. Outras vezes, a gente quer sacar um valor um pouco maior e por questões de segurança gostaria de receber tudo em notas de R$100,00, mas a máquina entrega um monte de notas de R$20,00. O Banco Inteligente está tentando minimizar esse problema dando aos clientes a possibilidade de escolher o valor das notas na hora do saque. Para isso, eles precisam da sua ajuda para saber, dado o valor S do saque e quantas notas de cada valor a máquina tem, quantas formas distintas existem de entregar o valor S. O banco disponibiliza notas de 2, 5, 10, 20, 50 e 100. Por exemplo, se S = 22 e o número de notas de cada valor é N2=5, N5=4, N10=3, N20 = 10, N50 = 0 e N100=10, então há 4 formas distintas da máquina entregar o valor do saque: 20+2, 10+10+2, 10+5+5+2 e 5+5+5+5+2.
>
> ### Entrada
>
> A primeira linha da entrada contém um inteiro S, o valor do saque. A segunda linha contém seis inteiros N2, N5, N10, N20, N50 e N100, respectivamente, o número de notas de valores 2,5,10,20,50 e 100, disponíveis na máquina.
>
> ### Saída
>
> Seu programa deve imprimir um inteiro, o número de formas distintas da máquina entregar o saque.

Eu só não sei como fazer para contar quantas possibilidades, ainda mais que existem muitas maneiras. Até agora isso foi o que consegui implementar no meu código (A função forms obviamente não está nem um pouco implementada):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
  int q;
  int v;
}din;

int start(din n[],int t,int i){
  if(t>=n[i].v) return i;
  else return start(n,t,i-1);
}

int forms(din n[6],int t,int i){
  int x,k=t,c=0;
  if(n[x].q==0) return forms(n,t,i-1);
  else{
    if(k==0){
      c++;
    }
    else{ 
    }
  } 
}

int main(void){
  int t,x;
  din n[6];
  scanf("%d",&t);
  for(x=0;x<6;x++) scanf("%d",&n[x].q);
  for(x=0;x<6;x++){
    if(x==0) n[x].v=2;
    else if(x==1) n[x].v=5;
    else if(x==2) n[x].v=10;
    else if(x==3) n[x].v=20;
    else if(x==4) n[x].v=50;
    else if(x==5) n[x].v=100;
  }
  printf("%d\n",forms(n,t,start(n,t,5));
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Já notei que não tem retorno para o caso base. Então o C assumirá 0. Como você só retorna o caso recursivo (não uma soma dessa recursão com algo a mais, o que indica outro erro), ele acabará por sempre retornar 0.

Comment: Sim, mas pra implementar a função eu preciso pelo menos saber como calcular quantas possibilidades de entregar uma quantia x de dinheiro. É isso que não tenho ideia :/

Comment: Bem, um comentário rápido: este não é um problema fácil, e eu sugiro estudar retrocesso (backtracking) e programação dinâmica.

Answer (score 1):

Esse problema é conhecido, em inglês, como "coin change problem" e caso haja interesse basta você dar uma pesquisada rápida no Google que você consegue entender como todas as possibilidades são calculadas.

Mas o problema que você apresentou, em específico, tem uma particularidade interessante: a quantidade de notas é limitada. Na maioria das soluções que você vai encontrar na internet, trabalha-se com uma quantidade infinita de notas (ou moedas)

Bem, eu fiz algumas alterações no seu código e substitui as funções `start(args)` e `forms(args)` por uma função só chamada `count(args)`. Depois testei com o caso que você apresentou e mais alguns outros e **aparentemente está funcionando**. A solução segue abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
   int q;
   int v;
}din;

int count(din notas[], int indice, int saque){

   if(saque == 0) {return 1;}

   if(saque < 0){return 0;}

   if(indice < 0){return 0;}

   int esq, dir;

   if (notas[indice].q <= 0){
      esq = 0;

   } else {

      /*Para se controlar o número de notas, subtrai-se antes de chamar a função e,
      com o retorno da função, restitui-se o valor ao estado anterior*/
      notas[indice].q--;
      esq = count(notas, indice, saque - notas[indice].v);
      notas[indice].q++;
   }
   dir = count(notas, indice - 1, saque);
   return esq + dir;
}

int main(void){
  int t,x;
  din n[6];
  scanf("%d",&t);
  for(x=0;x<6;x++) scanf("%d",&n[x].q);
  for(x=0;x<6;x++){
    if(x==0) n[x].v=2;
    else if(x==1) n[x].v=5;
    else if(x==2) n[x].v=10;
    else if(x==3) n[x].v=20;
    else if(x==4) n[x].v=50;
    else if(x==5) n[x].v=100;
  }
  printf("%d\n",count(n, 5, t));
  return 0;
}
```